# Php get value in select tag

Tags: php, mysql

I have table country

- id : int
- name : varchar(255)

I would like to get the value in the update  than i selected in addition in tag : `<select><option></option> </select>`.

page add.php :

```
<select class="form-control" name="name">
      <option>USA</option>
      <option>England</option>
      <option>French</option>
      <option>Italie</option>
      <option>Belguim</option>
</select>
```

I made this code but not fetch me the value  in the select tag in the page update.php when i has entered in the page add.php

page update.php :

```
<select class="form-control" name="name" value ="<?php echo $row['name'] ?>" >
          <option>USA</option>
          <option>England</option>
          <option>French</option>
          <option>Italie</option>
          <option>Belguim</option>
    </select>
```

Comment: I think you're looking for html `selected` in `<option>`

Comment: unsure of ur question but i think it should be <select><option value="usa">usa</option></select>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to iterate the result of your query and create an `<option>` for each result.

```
$result = mysql_query($query); // Your selection query

<select class="form-control" name="name">
     while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))  
        echo '<option>'.$row['name'].</option>';
</select>
```